# HM-10 can't communicate with Nuvoton MCU

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I use HM-10 module with NuTiny MS51 development board. This board has 8 bit MS51FB9AE microprocessor.

First I have tried the Bluetooth module with Arduino to see if it works. It worked in Arduino serial monitor. The settings were 9600 baud rate and both NL & CR in Arduino serial monitor.

This is the Arduino code which worked.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial HM10(2,3);

char rx_buffer[150];
unsigned int index = 0;
unsigned char response;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  HM10.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  HM10.listen();
  while (HM10.available() > 0)
  {
    char data = HM10.read();
    if (index < (sizeof(rx_buffer) - 1))
    {
      rx_buffer[index++] = data;
      if (data == '\n')
      {
        rx_buffer[index++] = '\0';
        Serial.println(rx_buffer);
        index = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  if (Serial.available())
  {
    HM10.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

I modified the code. This is the code that I am working on currently.In this code I send AT? command every second.

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                                                                                         */
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0                                                                     */
/* Copyright(c) 2020 Nuvoton Technology Corp. All rights reserved.                                         */
/*                                                                                                         */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "ms51_16k.h"

#define STATE_DELAY_TIME         1000
#define RECEIVE_DATA_LENGTH      30

// Global variables
volatile uint16_t systemTick = 0;

uint8_t state = 0;
uint16_t stateFirstTime = 0;
uint16_t stateSecondTime = 0;


volatile uint8_t rxBuffer[RECEIVE_DATA_LENGTH];
volatile uint8_t index = 0;


/************************************************************************************************************/
/* PROTOTYPES                                                                                                               */
/************************************************************************************************************/
void timer_1ms_init();
uint16_t millis();

void UART1_Init(void);
void send_at_command(void);
void analyse_data(char*);


/************************************************************************************************************/
/* ISR FUNCTIONS                                                                                                        */
/************************************************************************************************************/
void Timer2_ISR (void) interrupt 5        // Vector @  0x2B
{
_push_(SFRS);
    systemTick++;
    clr_T2CON_TF2;
_pop_(SFRS);
}


void SerialPort1_ISR(void) interrupt 15
{
    _push_(SFRS);

    if (RI_1)
    {
        uart1_receive_data = SBUF_1;
        printf("uart1_receive_data  = %c\n",uart1_receive_data );
        if (index < RECEIVE_DATA_LENGTH - 1)
        {
            rxBuffer[index++] = uart1_receive_data;
            if (uart1_receive_data == '\n')
            {
                rxBuffer[index] = '\0';
                analyse_data(rxBuffer);
            }
        }
        RI_1 = 0;
    }
        
    if (TI_1 == 1)
    {
        if (!PRINTFG)
        {
            clr_SCON_1_TI_1;                             /* if emission occur */
        }
    }

    _pop_(SFRS);
}

/************************************************************************************************************/
/* FUNCTION_PURPOSE: Main Loop                                                                              */
/************************************************************************************************************/
void main (void) 
{
        // Init functions
    MODIFY_HIRC(HIRC_24);
    Enable_UART0_VCOM_printf_24M_115200();
    UART1_Init();
    timer_1ms_init();       // led blink on electronic board
        
    P12_PUSHPULL_MODE;
    P12 = 1;
    ENABLE_GLOBAL_INTERRUPT;
    
    
    while(1)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                state = 1;
            }break;
                
            case 1:
            {
                stateFirstTime = millis();
                // printf("stateFirstTime = %u\r",stateFirstTime);
                state = 2;
            }break;
            case 2:
            {
                stateSecondTime = millis();
                // printf("stateSecondTime = %u\n",stateSecondTime);
                if (stateSecondTime - stateFirstTime > STATE_DELAY_TIME)
                {
                    P12 ^= 1;
                    send_at_command();
                    state = 0;
                }
            }break;
        }
            
    }

}


/************************************************************************************************************/
/* TIMER RELATED FUNCTIONS                                                                                      */
/************************************************************************************************************/
void timer_1ms_init()
{
    // Timer2_AutoReload_Interrupt_Initial(24,300000);
    TIMER2_DIV_128;
    TIMER2_Auto_Reload_Delay_Mode;
    RCMP2L = TIMER_DIV128_VALUE_1ms_FOSC_24000000;
    RCMP2H = TIMER_DIV128_VALUE_1ms_FOSC_24000000 >> 8;
    TL2 = 0;
    TH2 = 0;

    set_ET2;    // Set timerinterrupt
    set_TR2;    // Start timer
}

uint16_t millis()
{
    return systemTick;
}


/************************************************************************************************************/
/* UART RELATED FUNCTIONS                                                                                       */
/************************************************************************************************************/
void UART1_Init(void)
{
    P16_QUASI_MODE;
    P02_INPUT_MODE;
    UART_Open(24000000, UART1_Timer3 , 9600);
    ENABLE_UART1_INTERRUPT;
}

void send_at_command(void)
{
    UART_Send_Data(UART1,'A');
    UART_Send_Data(UART1,'T');
    UART_Send_Data(UART1,'?');
    UART_Send_Data(UART1,'\r');
    UART_Send_Data(UART1,'\n');
}

void analyse_data(char buffer[])
{
    int i = 0;
    
    while (buffer[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c",buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }
        
    printf("\n");
        
    index = 0;
}
```

I checked the UART communication in the `UART_Send_Data()` function to see if I send the command correctly.

```
void UART_Send_Data(unsigned char UARTPort, unsigned char c)
{
    _push_(SFRS);
    SFRS = 0;
    switch (UARTPort)
    {
        case UART0:
          TI=0;
          SBUF = c;
          while(!TI);
        break;
        case UART1:
          TI_1=0;
          SBUF_1 = c;
          printf("%c\n",c);
          while(!TI_1);
        break;
    }
    _pop_(SFRS);
}
```

The result in Putty screen looks like this. I don't get the response from HM-10 Module.

[image]

To be honest I am not even sure what's the problem here? Can't I send \r\n here over UART?

How can I overcome this problem ?

Thanks to all.